# How to use Ternary Operator in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs

Incase the name is undefined ,  i need to show blank or else append Hi 
  I am using React functional Component

```
let NamesComp = ({namesdata}) =>


  <div>
    <div className="srsPanel">
      <div className="crs">Name 1:</div>

      <div className="dse" ><div className="data">{(namesdata.name == undefined ? "":'Hi'{namesdata.name} </div></div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

```
let NamesComp = ({ namesdata }) =>
  <div>
    <div className="srsPanel">
      <div className="crs">Name 1:</div>
      <div className="dse">
        <div className="data">
          {namesdata.name === undefined ?
            "" :
            `Hi ${namesdata.name}`
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Use triple equals instead of double equals too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator):

```
let NamesComp = ({namesdata}) =>
  <div>
    <div className="srsPanel">
      <div className="crs">Name 1:</div>
      <div className="dse"><div className="data">{(namesdata.name && `Hi${namesdata.name}` </div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It's a little cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

Go with ES6+ features of JS. Even better than ternary operator will be to use short-circuit evaluation with `&&`. This way - if there will be any value on `namesdata.name` it will be evaluated and name will be printed. Other way, if there will be no `namesdata.data`, no text will be printed in this div.

```
let NamesComp = ({namesdata}) =>
  <div>
    <div className="srsPanel">
      <div className="crs">Name 1:</div>
      <div className="dse"><div className="data">{(namesdata.name && `Hi${namesdata.name}`)} </div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The ternary operator isn't an ES6 feature ;)